# Oracle database : ORA.01034:ORACLE not available

Tags: database, oracle

I installed oracle 12c r2 in ubuntu 18.04 and when I enter SqlPlus and execute a query it gives me error.

To install the oracle I followed these two guides:

1- https://tutorialforlinux.com/2018/05/09/how-to-install-oracle-12c-r2-database-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-64bit-easy-guide/
2- https://etc.to/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=20480023

The error that gives me is the following:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034:ORACLE not available
Process ID:0
Session ID: Serial numbre:0
```

The status of the listener (lsnrctl status) gives me the following error:

```
Connectinc to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST)(PORT=1521))
TNS-12541:TNS: no listener
tns-12560 TNS:protocol adapter error
TNS-00511: No listener
Linux error:111: Connection refused
```

Can anybody help me?Thanks!!

MORE INFO

now when I put lsnrctl status I get this, but in sqlplus the failure of above still appears

```
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on 19-OCT-2018 01:53:18

Copyright (c) 1991, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                19-OCT-2018 01:52:14
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 1 min. 5 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/andoni-VirtualBox/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=andoni-VirtualBox)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
```

Startup error:

```
    Enter user-name: sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> startup
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/u01/app/oracle/product/12/dbhome_1/dbs/initSID.ora'
SQL>
```

Comment: Maybe the database is not up. You can run ps -ef | grep pmon to look for the pmon process. You could run sqlplus / as sysdba and then type startup.

Comment: when I execute the command I get the error that I will leave in the post,but in this directory i dont have initxe.ora only init.ora

Comment: Look at the second answer below. Your ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID have to be set correctly. Oracle home is probably /u01/app/oracle/product/12/dbhome_1. Looks like you don't have ORACLE_SID set. It is probably ORCL.

Comment: Could you post the output of the following two Linux shell commands: ps -ef | grep pmon and set | grep ORACLE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit the tnsnames.ora file
u01/app/oracle/product/12/client_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora

```
MY_BASE_DEV =
  (DESCRIPTION =
     (ADDRESS_LIST =
       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = 192.168.2.1) (PORT = 1521))
     )
     (CONNECT_DATA =
       (SERVICE_NAME = BASEDEV)
     )
   )

MY_BASE_PROD =
  (DESCRIPTION =
     (ADDRESS_LIST =
       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = 192.168.2.2) (PORT = 1521))
     )
     (CONNECT_DATA =
       (SERVICE_NAME = BASEPROD)
     )
   )
```

Comment: The listener seems to work, but sqlplus continues to fail 
when I try to make a query or create a user

Answer (score 0):

You may have to set ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID environment variables:

need to do the following:

```
export ORACLE_HOME='HOME PATH VARIABLE'
export ORACLE_SID=<SID>
sqlplus "/as sysdba"
startup
```

The fields `ORACLE_HOME, ORACLE_SID` should match. Small things like no trailing '/' in the `ORACLE_HOME` are important.